# How do I set up my JavaFX project as a Gradle build?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, javafx

I've created a new JavaFX project via the e(fx)clipse plugin, then staged and committed to Git.  Following that I tried to run it and got a 'class not found' error - needed to add JavaFX to the --module-path in VM arguments.  But it still won't run:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Java\AdoptOpenJDK\javafx-sdk-13.0.2\lib
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\Java\AdoptOpenJDK\javafx-sdk-13.0.2\lib
```

Then I noticed that I have no build files in the project tree - no pom.xml or build.gradle, etc.
[image]

I decided to build with Gradle (previously only used Maven).  After a lot of hunting on the net I did the following:

1. Project context menu -> Configure -> Add Gradle nature (this didn't visibly do anything, but the option is no longer available).
2. In the Gradle Tasks view, run `init`. (This ran fine until it got to `Execute setupProjectLayout for :init`.  This got stuck and I let it sit for about 20 mins, but there was no activity (checked task manager to confirm)).
   [image]

There must be something fundamental that I'm missing here, surely it shouldn't be this difficult.  How can I get this project to build in Gradle?

Comment: Did you have a look here? https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: Ugh, I fixed the class not found issue :(

It was just a typo in the `module-path`.  I didn't put the "" around the path to javaFX and there is a space in the directory.

Still can't get `init` to run though..

Comment: Tried to start from scratch with a new Gradle project (instead of JavaFX project like before).  Seemed to set up OK, but then couldn't get the `run` task to complete.  Gradle really seems like more effort than what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle `init` task is an *interactive* task to generate a new Gradle project. If you run it from the IDE but have no way to provide answers to the prompts from Gradle, it will indeed wait forever on an input.

Comment: Oh. How do I provide the input via Gradle then?  I haven’t seen any prompts in console or elsewhere.

Comment: I would recommend using the CLI for `init`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a CLI for input.

After you run the gradle task in the "Gradle Tasks" view you switch to the "Console" view and you are presented with the questions by gradle init. You answer those questions and finish the task.

```
Working Directory: /path/to/your/project/thenewgradleproject
Gradle user home: /home/user/.gradle
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 6.8
Java Home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: init

> Task :wrapper UP-TO-DATE

Select type of project to generate:
  1: basic
  2: application
  3: library
  4: Gradle plugin
Enter selection (default: basic) [1..4] 

> Task :init

Select build script DSL:
  1: Groovy
  2: Kotlin
Enter selection (default: Groovy) [1..2] 

Project name (default: thenewgradleproject): 


> Task :init
Get more help with your project: Learn more about Gradle by exploring our samples at https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/samples

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 53s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```